# Apache Passenger with PassengerBaseURI

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger

I'm trying to setup portus with docker registry on the same host. For this I used the configuration provided [here](http://port.us.org/docs/setups/4_portus_and_registry_on_the_same_fqdn.html#apache2) but without ssl. The problem is, that on `example.com/portus` I get "Not Found: /" but on `example.com/portus/portus` the application is running.

This is my config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/portus.*$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ "http:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1\:5000\/$1" [P,L] 

Alias /portus /srv/Portus/public
<Location /portus>
  PassengerBaseURI /portus
  PassengerAppRoot /srv/Portus
</Location>

<Directory /srv/Portus/public>
   # This relaxes Apache security settings.
   AllowOverride all
   # MultiViews must be turned off.
   Options -MultiViews
   # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
   Require all granted
   SetEnv GEM_PATH /srv/Portus/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0
   SetEnv PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY 0
   SetEnv PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY 0
   PassengerAppEnv production
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```